# DocBin to_bytes/to_disk gets killed

Tags: python, python-3.x, spacy, spacy-3

I am dealing with fairly big corpuses and my **DocBin** object gets killed when I try to save it. Both **to_disk** and **to_bytes** are printing **"Killed"**.

I am with limited python knowledge, so it isn't obvious to me right away how I can work around the issue. Can you help?

Here is my code(very straight forward and basic):

````
    nlp = spacy.blank("en")
    for text, annotations in train_data:
        doc = nlp(text)
        ents = []
        for start, end, label in eval(annotations)['entities']:
            span = doc.char_span(start, end, label=label)
            if (span is None):
                continue
            ents.append(span)   
        doc.ents = ents
        db.add(doc)

    db.to_disk("../Spacy/train.spacy")```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably running out of RAM. Instead, save your annotation in multiple `DocBin` files. You can provide a directory to `--paths.train` with `spacy train` instead of a single `.spacy` file if you have multiple `.spacy` files.